# PHP PDO Update no funciona

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

Estoy haciendo el siguiente **UPDATE** y no sé porqué lo único que se modifica es la columna `disponible`, pero el resto se quedan tal cual.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE users_stats SET disponible = :disponible 
        AND ultimo = :ultimo AND total = total + :total WHERE user = :user");
$stmt->bindParam(':disponible ', $disponible);
$stmt->bindParam(':ultimo', $cantidad);
$stmt->bindParam(':total', $cantidad);
$stmt->bindParam(':user', $id);
$stmt->execute();
```

Haciendo un echo de `$cantidad` veo lo siguiente: `50.000000`

La columna ultimo y total son `FLOAT(12,6)`.

Answer (score 1):

Debes separar con coma no con `AND`

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE users_stats SET disponible = :disponible, ultimo = :ultimo, total = total + :total WHERE user = :user");
$stmt->bindParam(':disponible ', $disponible);
$stmt->bindParam(':ultimo', $cantidad);
$stmt->bindParam(':total', $cantidad);
$stmt->bindParam(':user', $id);
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu sintaxis es incorrecta.  Tienes que separar con comas las columnas asi:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE users_stats SET disponible = :disponible, ultimo = :ultimo, total = total + :total WHERE user = :user");
```